# how to convert X to Y and Y to X at the same time in a string in python

Tags: python, string

Assume that we have a string like:XYYX. I want to get YXXY.How do I do that in python?

couldnt think of anything

Comment: [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) will do that.

Comment: Replace all X's with some character that does not appear in the string, perhaps a semicolon.  Then replace all Y's with X's, then replace the semicolons with Y's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
str = str.replace("X", "*")
str = str.replace("Y", "X")
str = str.replace("*", "Y")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just iterate through the string and swap them.

```
def invert(str):
  newstr = ""
  for i from 0 to len(str):
    if str[i] == 'X':
      newstr += 'Y'
    else:
      newstr += 'X'
  return newstr
```

Could also just modify the original string.

Edit: I'm assuming this is some kind of from-scratch school assignment

Edit2: My python is a bit rusty, so forgive any syntax errors and treat it as pseudocode if you must; 'tis far from gospel

Answer (score 0):

As Chris suggested:

```
string = "XYYX"
table = str.maketrans("XY", "YX")
string.translate(table)

'YXXY'
```